# How to take care of geraniums?

Tags: flowers, watering, geraniums

The leaves are turning yellow on my geraniums. Am I over watering them or are they getting too much? What is causing this? I have only had them a couple of weeks.

Comment: What kind of geraniums? True [geraniums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geranium) or [Pelargoniums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelargonium) which are commonly sold as "Geraniums". Are they in containers or in the ground? How much sun do they get? What are they planted in: soil, potting compost, etc.

Comment: Please describe your recent weather and how you've been caring for them. What types/size containers are they in, how much and often you water/fertilize, how much sun, etc. Pictures would be nice too.

Comment: What part of the world are you in? Please edit your question to include extra information

Comment: @NiallC. To be pedant, both of them are _Geranium_ and it is correct to call them _Geranium_ (according rules of botanic nomenclature). Just that _Geranium_ genus was split very early, but after Linnaeus)